# (php) Why are all trailing zeros ignored when called from url?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I have a serious problem. I am trying to show messages in a page from the database. Everything is working fine except that my php code cannot differentiate 2, 20, 200, 2000, 20000 and so on. the same with 1, 100, 1000 etc. I think the problem is that the trailing zeros are being ignored.

When a message is sent to a person with id 20, the ones with both id 2 and 200 will see the messages.

Here is the code:

```
    if(isset($_GET['sent_to']) {
        $message_to = $_GET['sent_to'];
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['me'];
        $slash =".";
        $involved = $message_to . $slash. $cookie ;

        $swap = $cookie .$slash. $message_to ;

        $query = "select * from (
            select * from messages where involved = {$involved} or involved = {$swap} order by id desc limit 10
        ) sub
        order by id asc";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
    } 

    if(!empty($result)) {
        while($fetch_result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
            echo $fetch_result['message'];  
    ?>
```

The problem is, if `$message_to` is 20, it will not differentiate it from 2, 200, 2000 and so on. it is like it ignores all trailing zeros from the url. Someone help me.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why would you expect this to work when you are buidling concatenated strings for use with searching an INT id field?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And did you do any basic debugging like checking `var_dump($_GET)` and `var_dump($_COOKIE)` to see what you're really getting? Don't just ASSUME things. always look at the inputs and what you're generating with those inputs.

Comment: $involved and $swap both contain cookie values connected to the $_GET['sent_to'] with a dot between them. I showed it above

Comment: `100.20` looks like a float to the system, so there is no difference between `100.2`, `100.20`, `100.20000`, etc

Comment: Mark B, I did that. If I write 2000, var_dump will give me string(4) "2000" which is ok. but when it comes to displaying the values of 2, 200 and 20, it displays the same thing.

Comment: If you need to treat this as a string comparison, then quote the values, else MySQL will assume you want a numeric comparison

Comment: Mark Baker, So should I use a comma instead? I think that would work for now... or is there any other thing to do to avoid that?

Comment: Having 2 columns on your database would probably be easier (you wouldn't need to build `$swap` in your PHP code either); but if you have to use a separator then use something that can't be misinterpreted, and quote it as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its defaulting to a numeric comparison.

Assuming `$cookie` is numeric your string is 100.2 and 100.20 which are the same number.

Force MySQL to use string comparison by quoting the variable

```
select * from messages where involved = {$involved} or involved = '{$swap}' order by id desc limit 10
```

note the `'` around `swap` now

this will cpompare as strings where `100.2` and `100.20` are different

Also as others have noted, this is vunrable to SQL injection and also uses deprecated code. Please fix this errors also.

you should also probably look at your database design as it currently doesnt seem to hold the data correctly. one column should contain one peice of data. not a `.` separated value containing 2 pieces of data

Comment: I have been enjoying doing php for six months now, and in every question I ask, there is this comment about vulnerability to SQL injection. I have never understood it so far. I hope I will understand it soon.

Comment: @stackoverflowfan its when you send directly the users input to the query. You need to either filter it or preferably use prepared statements

Comment: I love your answer. Clear and precise and fully working. Thanks alot.

Comment: I removed them for this question. I usually strip html and real_escape.